# Retrieving data from firebase database in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm recently migrated to Firebase. I have gone through Firebase Android api docs for retrieving data from database through JSON. there is method `onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)` to retrieve data whenever there is change in data in database but I could find how to retrieve data even if there is no change in database.

For example:- when a user logs into my app, I want that data which is stored under the unique id node should be retrieved. How can I retrieve data anytime from Firebase database if i want?

Comment: if you want retrieve data from firebase, just create a reference object of your desired firebase path. Firebase ref=new Firebase(path);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Firebase guide on reading data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html):

> [the `onDataChange()` method is] triggered once with the initial data and again every time the data changes.

I highly recommend that you read the [Firebase guide for Android programming](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/) end-to-end. It'll answer many of the questions you're likely to have as you start using Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Read and Write Database Guide lines:
 https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

```
public class NavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
 @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }


 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

initializeAuthListener();

 mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();



}

private void initializeAuthListener() {
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                try {
                    if (firebaseAuth != null) {
                        loadUserDetails();
                        Log.d("@@@@", "thread:signed_in:" + firebaseUser.getUid());
                    } else {
                        Log.d("@@@@", "thread:signed_out");
                        Intent login = new Intent(NavigationActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(login);
                        finish();
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Intent login = new Intent(NavigationActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(login);
                    finish();
                }

            }
        };
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

private void loadUserDetails() {
        DatabaseReference userReference = mDatabase
                .child("users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());

//        displayUserDetails(userReference);
        userReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                tv_user_name.setText(user.getDisplayName());
                tv_user_email_nav.setText(user.getEmail());

                Glide.with(NavigationActivity.this)
                        .load(user.getPhotoUrl())
                        .placeholder(R.mipmap.profile)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .dontAnimate()
                        .bitmapTransform(new CropCircleTransformation(NavigationActivity.this))
                        .into(iv_user_image);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
//                Toast.makeText(ThreadActivity.this, R.string.error_loading_user, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45328201/5973946