# How to save images from Firebase DB to a drawable list on Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, picasso

I am having a problem with my Android code. I am developing a game on Android. I first stored my images on resource file. But now I want to store them on Firebase. My plan was to download them using Picasso and add them to an Arraylist. But it doesnt have a method for returning just a drawable object. I tried to fetch BitMap and convert it to a drawable but it didnt work.

```
    flagImages=new ArrayList<Drawable>();
    flagImages.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.flag1));
    flagImages.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.flag2));
    flagImages.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.flag3));
```

I want to change the code above. Do you have any ideas? What should I use? My primary aim is to put the images into my ArrayList.

Comment: upload the image into firebase storage, and then save the url in firebase, and also, i would suggest glide then picasso, especially for memory performance

Comment: But how do I download the data? Should I use bitmap? thus glide and picasso doesnt output drawable object

Comment: This link for all Firebase listing data and images in drawable resource https://stackoverflow.com/a/45328201/5973946

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1**: Upload all your images into `Firebase Storage`. Every image that is uploaded has a specific `reference` which you'll be able to save in the `Firebase Database` under a node named `links`.

**Step 2**: Attach a `listener` on the `link` node and get all the reference of your images.

**Step3**: You will need this build dependency:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.2.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

**Step4**: Load images from the `Firebase` `StorageReference` using `Glide` instead of `Picasso`.

```
Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
    .using(new FirebaseImageLoader()) // <== ADD THIS
    .load(storageReference)
    .signature(new StringSignature(localFile.length() + "@" + localFile.lastModified()))
    .into(images.get(i));
```

Step 5: Add your images into your `ArrayList`.