# How to get the list of all children in Firebase android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this model below in Firebase

[image: model]

I am trying to get all the values from child node posts using below code

```
  databasePostsReference = 
  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("posts");

 final List<UserPostPOJO> list = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;

  databasePostsReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: entered list adding");
                UserPostPOJO post = snapshot.getValue(UserPostPOJO.class);
                list.add(post);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

but I am getting error `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`.

in the above scenario i know that error is because list is declared final and i am trying to assign value in onDataChangeMethod so is throwing error but if i am not declaring the list variable final then i cant access list variable from within the onDataChange() method how to solve this

```
  public class UserPostPOJO {
    String uid;
    Double elevation;
    String uri;
    String feel;

    public UserPostPOJO() {
    }

    public UserPostPOJO(String uid, Double elevation, String uri, String feel) {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.elevation = elevation;
        this.uri = uri;
        this.feel = feel;
    }

    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public Double getElevation() {
        return elevation;
    }

    public void setElevation(Double elevation) {
        this.elevation = elevation;
    }

    public String getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public void setUri(String uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    public String getFeel() {
        return feel;
    }

    public void setFeel(String feel) {
        this.feel = feel;
    }
    }
```

Error Log:

```
  05-08 22:19:49.706 6421-6421/redeyes17.com.abhi.android.iamat                      
    D/recentfragment: onDataChange: entered list adding
   05-08 22:19:49.726 6421-6421/redeyes17.com.abhi.android.iamat 
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

   Process: redeyes17.com.abhi.android.iamat, PID: 6421

   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

   at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:404)

   at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:425)

   at redeyes17.com.abhi.android.iamat.UI.tabs
  .RecentFragment$1.onDataChange(RecentFragment.java:78)

  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpx.zza(Unknown Source)

  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqx.zzZT(Unknown Source)

  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbra$1.run(Unknown Source)

   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)

  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230)

  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller
 .run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)

 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Hi Abhilash. It would help if you could post the complete logs and the `UserPostPojo` class. Cheers!

Comment: Hi @AL. thanks for replying i posted the code after reading lot of articles i learnt that firebase operations are asynchronous operations so trying to assign values from inside the onDataChange method to a global variable would throw exception to make global variable final after declaring global final you cant assign anything here , so fix was to make callbacks and when you want to assign you have to use callback to assign but i dont know how to use callbacks can you please explain it if this all makes anysense

Comment: This is resolve your issue :https://stackoverflow.com/a/45328201/5973946

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all those values please use this code:

```
    databasePostsReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("posts").child(postId);
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           List<UserPostPOJO> list = new ArrayList<>();

           String elevation = (String) dataSnapshot.child("elevation").getValue();
           String feel = (String) dataSnapshot.child("feel").getValue();
           String uid = (String) dataSnapshot.child("uid").getValue();
           String uri = (String) dataSnapshot.child("uri").getValue();

          UserPostPOJO userPostPOJO = new UserPostPOJO();
          userPostPOJO.setElevation(elevation);
          userPostPOJO.setFeel(feel);
          userPostPOJO.setUid(uid);
          userPostPOJO.setUri(uri);

          list.add(userPostPOJO);
    }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
databasePostsReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

In which `postId` is the unique id generated by the `push()` method. And notice, that the declaration of your `list` must be inside the `onDataChange()` method, otherwise, you'll get null.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Alex eventually i figured it out this way , this works . I was wondering if we can assign the local list in onDataChange method to the list in global variable.

Comment: Happy to hear that you figure it out. No, you cannot make the `list` a global variable because `onDataChange` method is called asynchronously. This means that the statement that adds data to the list is executed before `onDataChange` is called and as said you'll get it `null`. If you want to learn more aboute this, pleas visit this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43576441/querying-data-from-firebase) and this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33723139/wait-firebase-async-retrive-data-in-android).

Comment: If you think that my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to accept it but couldnot because i have low reputation if myquestion is valid please up vote it and i have one more question if you dont mind answering it. i have this firebase child whose childs are all push keys how to sort them in ascending and descending order, basically want to retrieve recent ones but when i put in recycler view recent one is moving to the end of the recycler view how to handle this